# I have a typescript mern stack application that I am trying to host on vercel

Tags: typescript, express, mern

I have a typescript mern stack application that I am trying to host on vercel. I have successfully uploaded the react frontend but I am struggling with the express typescript server. It seems my build scripts are the problem. The error I am getting from my build logs on vercel is here.

```
WARN! Due to `builds` existing in your configuration file, the Build and Development Settings defined in your Project Settings will not apply. Learn More: https://vercel.link/unused-build-settings
```

This is what my package.json build scripts look like

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "start": "node build src/index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon --watch \"src/**\" --ext \"ts,json\" --exec \"ts-node src/index.ts\""
  },
```

Here is the vercel.json file

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "*.js",
            "use": "@vercel/node"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "/src/index.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your package.json file has a build script attribute that skips any custom Vercel settings. try to remove the `build` from **package.json**